# Convergence in measure.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ be i.i.d with

$$P(X_1=2^k-1)=\frac{1}{k(k+1)2^k} , k=1,2,\ldots$$

and $P(X_1=-1)=1-\sum_{k=1}^\infty P(X_1=2^k-1).$

Let $S_n=X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n$

> Then $$P\left(S_n < -\frac{n}{\log _2n}\right) \to 1$$

I think $S_n < \frac{-n}{\log_2n} $ means that how many $X_i$ $i=1,\ldots,n$ has value $-1$.

First I showed that $E(X)=0$.

But I couldn't do any more.

Could you help me?